# Jacobian of a parameterized homography ? $\frac{\partial{w(p)(x)}}{\partial{p}}$

Tags: optimization, lie-groups, lie-algebras, projective-geometry, lie-derivative

I am reading some paper about image warping. First of all it parameterized the homography with $p = (p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5,p_6,p_7,p_8)$ by using some lie algebra theory, because homography is a $sl(3,R)$.

The warping function is defined as : $w(p)(x)$ which transform a image coordinates (x,y) to another (x',y').

Afterwards, it needs to compute the Jacobian $J$ w.r.t $p$:

$J(p) = \frac{\partial{w(p)(x)}}{\partial{p}}$

The paper doesn't give the answer to the above equation. Could anybody tell me what is the $p$ here ? How could I get the Jacobian $J$ ?

Thanks!